# CDF Strange difference of line Plot display when switching from stylesheet "Normal" to "Journal Article" with "Manipulate"

Tags: manipulate, stylesheet, cdf-format

A LinePlot graphic with Manipulate works well in the CDF Player if i Use the stylesheet "Normal" but is rendered quite differently when I use the stylesheet "Journal Article". Here pieces of plots to illustrate the problem:[image: Default stylesheet] [image: Journal Article]. The first uses the stylesheet "Default", the second uses the stylesheet Journal Article.
Without Manipulate, the problem does not occur and the graphic appears as in the first picture, even if the Journal Article stylesheet is used.
I am using Mathematica 8.
Help would be appreciated
Ekkehart

Comment: Without code to reproduce the problem, it's difficult to say. But you might want to look at the ImageSize option to Manipulate. It may be as simple as making the imagesize larger to fit the rest of the plot.

Comment: Thank you, Bill! It is not a matter of image size, but of the plot lines that should look like in the notebook, but look quite differently in the CDF. The code is here: https://notebookarchive.org/season-nb--2021-04-c068cgy/. I wanted to create a CDF article using the manipulate section of that code (and some more). In  the meanwhile I checked with Mathematica 10. A similar problem arises there, too. /Ekkehart